# Hook functions defined by mixin not called for third-party plugin component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, mixins

I'm using Vue with the Vuetify plugin.

I'm extending Vue components globally with a mixin:

```
Vue.mixin({
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted');
    }
});
```

I see the log above for all of my own components but not for the `v-container` component of Vuetify.

Strange thing is, when I inspect the options of this component like so:

```
Vue.options.components['v-container'].options.mounted
```

I see that the `mounted` function defined by my mixin is added to the array of hooks.

After creating a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpkd38g5/) I was able to see it did work for all other Vuetify components.

> From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin):
>
> Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every
> single Vue instance created, including third party components.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem that can replicate it. I'd expect the mixin to work as expected under normal circumstances.

Comment: @EstusFlask Created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpkd38g5/. Most Vuetify components actually do work. The `v-container` isn't (updated question accordingly).

Comment: Update the question with relevant code, it will give the proper context to it because it's specific to actual code you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is specific to a component in use, [`v-container`](http://19822c315d572bdaff6fe/packages/vuetify/src/components/VGrid/VContainer.js#L5). It is [functional component](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/bb3ef969b0bbfda631219822c315d572bdaff6fe/packages/vuetify/src/components/VGrid/grid.js#L6) and functional components cannot have lifecycle methods, so ones defined in a mixin will be ignored.

As [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) describes functional components,

> It doesn’t manage any state, watch any state passed to it, and it has no lifecycle methods. Really, it’s only a function with some props.